# copy title from anchor and show in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-javascript-api

I need to make youtube video gallery play videos on the same page when one click's on the link it should play related video and copy title from the link and show it as  tag under video. .

So far i have do the video part need to how i can copy title from anchor link to a `title` div.

I would also appreciate a more professional way on doing the whole thing.

CODE on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSMZ9/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.vid_button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var URL = $(this).attr('href');
        var htm = '<iframe width="438" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '?wmode=transparent&rel=0&theme=light&color=white&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>';

        $('#video_container').html(htm);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/KSMZ9/3/)

add this code

```
$('.video-title').text($(this).text());
```

or

```
$('.video-title').text(this.innerHTML);
```

Reference

http://api.jquery.com/text/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML

Comment: I am a parttime code when it comes to jQuery. Can you tell me if this whole thing can me done in more efficient way. or it is fine..